# TTTAttributedLabel setbackground color

Tags: nsmutableattributedstring, tttattributedlabel

I am using TTTAttributedLabel and need to set background color. I can set text color like this.

```
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                 value:color
                 range:range];
    self.lblContent.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
```

But it is not working for background color.

```
    [mutableAttributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                 value:color
                 range:range];
    self.lblContent.attributedText = mutableAttributedString;
```

May I know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `kTTTBackgroundFillColorAttributeName`. See `TTTAttributedLabel.h` for details on that constant and several other attribute constants that are specific to `TTTAttributedLabel`.

Comment: also the value needs to be a CGColor, eg:  mutableAttrString.addAttribute(kTTTBackgroundFillColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor().CGColor, range: result.range)